# Why does this function return zero?

Tags: php

I have a function that is triggered via a jQuery ajax.

Within the function, I stop it via `return`. For example:

```
if ($processed_total < 3) {

    echo 'Post is successfully approved. ';

    return;
}
```

The problem is that the output will be:

> Post is successfully approved. 0

Note the zero at the end. Why is it there? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Here is the JS used for calling the function:

```
jQuery('.voteapproveform').submit(ajaxSubmit_voteapproveform);

function ajaxSubmit_voteapproveform(){

    var voteapproveform = jQuery(this).serialize();

    jQuery(this).parent().fadeOut(); // hide approve and reject button to prevent further voting

    jQuery.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: SiteParameters.site_url+"/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: voteapproveform,
        context: this,
        success:function(data){
            jQuery(this).fadeOut(); // hide approve box on submit
            jQuery(this).parent().next().html(data); // empty div .modboxfeedback to show returned data

        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

Comment: The 0 does not come from this code.

Comment: I suspected as much. But doesn't the return completely stop the function? Meaning that the offending code must be above the return?

Comment: Yes it does. So your 0 comes from somewhere else

Comment: It might be coming from above this condition

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Please show us your javascript code

Comment: @Uchiha How can it come *below* return? Given that return should stop the function, right?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson sorry my bad but that might be possible if the code is used between another functions

Comment: @HenrikPetterson: `return` stops *this function*. It does not stop *the code that called this function*.

Comment: @EugeneNezhuta See my updated question.

Comment: try if ($processed_total < 3) {

    echo 'Post is successfully approved. ';die; }

Comment: Instead of `return` try `exit`

Comment: @Uchiha exit solved this. But why? I still don't understand **why** I should exit/die here when return should be fine...

Comment: @HenrikPetterson For command line scripts, the return statement will NOT return a status to the OS! For that reason you need to use `exit` [Check This](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php#116709)

Comment: @Uchiha Do you mind posting an answer describing this in better detail?

Comment: @Uchiha Thanks for that link. This answers the question. Please describe it in a proper answer and I will accept this as correct.

Comment: in place of your  return; can u try  return 'check'; and tell me please whats the result ?

Comment: @captain_a I tried that, nothing special happened? Honestly, I have never heard of  return 'check';...??

Comment: oh that was just a check ;) .. the thing is, the zero definitely comes from the code that runs after return !.. you need to check what is next code in your flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**return**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) returns program control to the calling module. Execution resumes at the statement following the called module's invocation.

**Why does this function return zero?**

**If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function.** Not the rest of the other scripts or function.

> **For command line scripts, the return statement will NOT return a status to the OS!**

Instead, you must use [`exit()`](http://php.net/exit)

[Please refer Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)
[Also Check This Example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php#116709)

Answer (score -1):

Try this in a unit test environment if you are not sure if it comes from PHP or the JS.

> php -e filename.php

might help you, provided you do the groud work for it...

```
<?php
$processed_total = 2;
if ($processed_total < 3)
{
    echo 'Post is successfully approved. ';
    return;
}
echo "I am done with the test";
echo;
?>
```

Just by the looks of it, I am sure its not from the PHP code.